# How to load into an array all objects after Query Parse.com

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parse-platform

I'm using Parse.com as my backend and after Query how can I fill an array with all the data inside the Parse object? how can I avoid re-mapping? example:

```
$scope.addContList = contacts.map(function(obj) { // re-map!!!!
   return {name: obj.get("name")}; // mapping object using obj.get()
});
```

I'm mapping my Parse object's properties one by one: name: obj.get("name"), etc. is there a better way?

```
    $scope.addContList = [];
    var ActivityContact = Parse.Object.extend("ActivityContact2");
    var query = new Parse.Query(ActivityContact);
    query.equalTo("activityId", $scope.objId);
    query.find({
        success: function(contacts) {
            console.log("Successfully retrieved " + contacts.length + " contact.");
                $scope.$apply(function() {
                    /*$scope.addContList = contacts.map(function(obj) {
                        return {name: obj.get("name")}; // mapping object using obj.get()
                    });*/
                    for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
                          $scope.addContList.push(contacts.ALL_PROPERTIES); // contacts.ALL_PROPERTIES does not exist, I'm looking a way to do that and avoid mapping?
                    }
                });
            console.log("--->>>"+JSON.stringify($scope.addContList, null, 4));

        },
        error: function(object, error) {
            // The object was not retrieved successfully.
            // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and message.
        }
    });
```

1. Should I use Underscore library, is that the only way to go?
2. I have seen some ppl using PFQuery but I don't know what is that, is PFQuery better for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other answers are correct, but I think it's unnecessary to launch a digest cycle every time you add an item from `contacts` to `$scope.addContList`. Something like this should be sufficient:

```
query.find({
  success: function (contacts) {
    $scope.apply(function () {
      // 1) shallow-copy the list of contacts...
      // (this is essentially what you are trying to do now)
      $scope.addContList = contacts.slice();

      // or 2) just assign the reference directly
      $scope.addContList = contacts;

      // or 3) transform the Parse.Object instances into
      // plain JavaScript objects
      $scope.addContList = contacts.map(function (c) {
          return c.toJSON();
      });
    });
  },
  error: function (object, error) {
    // The object was not retrieved successfully.
    // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and message.
  }
});
```

Options 1) and 2) will correspond to a template similar to

```
<div ng-repeat="cont in addContList">{{ cont.get('name') }}</div>
```

while option 3) can be used like

```
<div ng-repeat="cont in addContList">{{ cont.name }}</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! 



I'm using $scope.addContList into a ng-repeat so I need an array of objects similar to this: [{name: "myname1"},{name: "myname2"},{name: "myname3"}]. If I use your solution I'll end up having ParseObject that I can't use (or at least not that easy). If you look at the code comments I have: $scope.addContList = contacts.map(function(obj) {return {name: obj.get("name")};}); I'm remapping the object for that same reason.

Comment: I see. So what was wrong with your `contacts.map(...)` solution?

Comment: I think is verbose and I'm looking for a better option. Thanks!

Comment: You can try something like `contacts.map(function (c) { return c.toJSON() }))`. This will of course copy all the properties of the `Parse.Object` into the plain JS object, but you can use whichever ones you need (`"name"` for example).

Comment: Also as you can see I need to use the obj.get() from Parse.com to get the actual value.

Comment: Another option is to just keep the array of `Parse.Object` instances and use them directly in `ng-repeat` as `<div ng-repeat="c in addContList">{{ c.get('name') }}</div>`.

Answer (score 2):

If you change

```
$scope.addContList = contacts[i];
```

to:

```
$scope.addContList.push(contacts[i]);
```

you should be good to go. Your previous code was re-assigning `addContList` to be each element in the `contacts` array, instead of adding the element to it. So at the end of your `for` loop, `$scope.addContList` would just be the last contact in your `contacts` array.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! 



I'm using $scope.addContList into a ng-repeat so I need an array of objects similar to this: [{name: "myname1"},{name: "myname2"},{name: "myname3"}]. If I use your solution I'll end up having ParseObject that I can't use (or at least not that easy). If you look at the code comments I have: $scope.addContList = contacts.map(function(obj) {return {name: obj.get("name")};}); I'm remapping the object for that same reason.

Comment: Can you please give provide a sample on plunker or jsfiddle?

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
$scope.addContList = contacts[i];
```

to

```
$scope.addContList.push(contacts[i]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! 



I'm using $scope.addContList into a ng-repeat so I need an array of objects similar to this: [{name: "myname1"},{name: "myname2"},{name: "myname3"}]. If I use your solution I'll end up having ParseObject that I can't use (or at least not that easy). If you look at the code comments I have: $scope.addContList = contacts.map(function(obj) {return {name: obj.get("name")};}); I'm remapping the object for that same reason.